# use confirm button to stop ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have code that show CONFIRM msg when I click on the A button.
 The problem is that my ajax continue and delete my record although I choose CANCEL.

Why is that?

```
<a href='#' class="btn btn-default btn-xs left delButton" type="comment" delID="<?PHP echo $subCommentIndex['id'] ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are u sure?')">Delete </a>
```

AJAX:

```
$(function() {

    $(document).on('click','.delButton',function() {

        var element = $(this);

        var delID = element.attr("delID");
        var type = element.attr("type");
        var info = 'delID=' + delID + '&type=' +  type;

         $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "ajax/delete_element.php",
           data: info,
           success: function(data){
                if (data == true)
                    $("#"+delID).animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
           }
         });

        return false;

    });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the confirm inside your javascript function as

```
$(function() {

$(document).on('click','.delButton',function() {

    var element = $(this);

    var delID = element.attr("delID");
    var type = element.attr("type");
    var info = 'delID=' + delID + '&type=' +  type;
    var check = confirm('Are you sure');
    if(check){
     $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "ajax/delete_element.php",
       data: info,
       success: function(data){
            if (data == true)
                $("#"+delID).animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
       }
     });
    }

    return false;

});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

add  "confirm('Are u sure?')" to your jq function.